# How to measure execution time of concurrent functions?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have `for` loop which executes goroutine. Here is the piece of code how it looks:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, photo := range photos {
        wg.Add(1)
        
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            start := time.Now()
            
            result := process(photo)
            
            fmt.Println("took %s", time.Since(start))
        }()
    }
    
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
    }()
```

In the above code, I want to count execution time of **each** `process(photo)` function. But the way I do it seems wrong. The numbers I get is not real. Where is my mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you think the result is wrong?

Comment: `go func() { wg.Wait() }()` has no effect.

Comment: The results is wrong because the printed execution time gets increasing. Because it is concurrent, time.Now() will be almost the same for every iteration. It means, time.Since will return weird values.

Comment: This is similar to saying the results of a race are wrong because the runners finished in increasing run times.

Comment: why wg.Wait has no effect?

Comment: *"the printed execution time gets increasing"* -- Of course it does. The one that finished first will get printed first because it took the shortest amount of time. The one that finished second will get printed second and its time will be the second shortest, and so on. The process that takes the longest to finish cannot be printed *before* all the other processes that already finished. Using concurrency will not bend time. And this does not mean that the first one printed equals the first one started. Or the last one printed was processing the last photo in the list.

Comment: It's not like you're waiting for all of them to finish and only then printing the times in the same order they started. The behaviour you describe is the correct behaviour. Your expectations are what's wrong. [This](https://go.dev/play/p/nHkF_KayjJN) is perfectly fine and *as advertised*.

Comment: ["Wait blocks until the WaitGroup counter is zero."](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup.Wait) You must call `Wait()` **in the goroutine which you want to wait**. Creating a goroutine which only waits has no effect because waiting in itself accomplishes nothing. You want to wait and **then** do things which should happen after waiting.

Comment: @mkopriva The problem I'm getting is the result shows that the last iteration of process function took 9 seconds (for instance). All of the `for` loop took 9 seconds also. But I'm sure that my process function cannot take 9 seconds. The goal I want to achieve is measuring of each `process` function execution time. Not all `for` loop execution time. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @neo as you can see from the linked playground, the above does measure the execution time of each individual process. The whole loop doesn't take a smidge of a second. However if you moved your timing-of-the-loop under the waitgroup then of course it will take approx. the same time as the slowest process because it is the slowest/last process that unblocks the waitgroup. https://go.dev/play/p/EjSYEouFm27

Comment: @neo as to the statement *"I'm sure that my process function cannot take 9 seconds."*, that I cannot address because I don't know the internals of your `process` implementation. You may be, but I cannot be sure it *"cannot"* take 9 seconds.

Comment: If you have a large number of photos, you will get more informative timings with a worker-job-queue pattern.

Comment: @neo if you take the slowest goroutine's `photo` input and process it a couple times alone, with no other photos being processed, and the time difference compared to when processed with the other goroutines turns out to be substantial, then it may be that your `process` implementation depends, under the hood, on some constrained resource, perhaps some mutex-locked shared instance or whatever.

Comment: @mkopriva The resource in question is probably the CPU if we're talking about image processing.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I concur.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating as many goroutines as you have pictures to process you would be better off creating as many goroutines as you have CPU cores so that there is no wasteful usage or exhaustion of system resources. Hand out one picture to every idle goroutine and make time it while it processes the picture. When picture processing is over and you stopped the timer, log the time and hand that goroutine another picture to process. No goroutines waiting to be scheduled that consume memory.

See https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools for a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the photo variable to your go-routine or introduce a local variable inside the for loop and pass that variable to `process()` function, otherwise all your go-routines will have the same instance of photo variable.

And, there is no point writing wg.Wait() in another go-routine. You can updated your code like this

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, photo := range photos {
        wg.Add(1)

        photo := photo

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            start := time.Now()
            
            result := process(photo)
            
            fmt.Println("took %s", time.Since(start))
        }()
  }
  wg.Wait()
```

Comment: I know about that. I passed photo to goroutine but it does not help and problem is not there. My output is following: 
took 700ms
took 953 ms
took 1.2 s
took 3.3s
took 3.8s
took 4s

All of my for loop gets finished in 4s. Output shows that the last process was finished in 4s. It is wrong definitely.

Comment: The go-routine takes longer time to finish, it prints later. Lets say, there are three go-routines. First one took 4s, second one took 1s and third one took 2s. So, the second go-routine will print the log first, then the third one and then first one. You should print the index of photo array by passing it into the go-routines

Comment: like u mentioned, all your loops finished in 4s, given the small func, it implies that the slowest thread completed the job using ~4s. That is the exact concept of concurrency! 

You should not be expecting the total process time to add up to ur funct completion time as that would means iterative and not concurrent